MERN Stack on Render Issues "Cannot GET /" error
Ive uploaded my front end as a static site on Render and my backend as a web service.
I am getting an error when opening the backend as "Cannot GET /" so when I try to use my react app there is not functionality.
I created environment variables for the JWT Token, MONG_URI for the mongodb atlas database.
If anyone can see anything wrong with my code please let me know, my github repo is:
frontend - Frontend
backend - Backend
Ive tried adding the port as it was in development as 4000 as an evironment variable but I dont think that has done anything.

Posting links off-site to seperate repos is not a good way to ask a question. Please provide a minimal reproducible example, following these instruections: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
